# Split word and check spelling error within article

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to check the spelling error within an aricle, I have 100 articles to check to see got spelling error of not, if got one error then word return 1 else 0. I have to split the article into words by word then only check. I have done all of these here, but the problem is i could not check the spelling error of the split word.However, I could check with

```
deliberate_mistake = 'tabel';
suggestion = checkSpelling(deliberate_mistake)
```

output:
suggestion =

```
'table'
```

checkSpelling.m file

```
function suggestion = checkSpelling(word)

h = actxserver('word.application');
h.Document.Add;
correct = h.CheckSpelling(word);
if correct
  suggestion = []; %return empty if spelled correctly
else
  %If incorrect and there are suggestions, return them in a cell array
  if h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).count > 0
      count = h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).count;
      for i = 1:count
          suggestion{i} = h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).Item(i).get('name');
      end
  else
      %If incorrect but there are no suggestions, return this:
      suggestion = 'no suggestions';
  end
end
%Quit Word to release the server
h.Quit
```

f20.m file

```
for i = 1:1

data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\',int2str(i),''),'r')
CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData
fclose(data2);

word =regexp(CharData,' ','split')

[sizeData b] = size(word);

suggestion = checkSpelling(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a cell array, try to give your function a single string input. Works for me.

Comment: i want the cell array by using the function. So, how to change the function to cell array? yes, it works well for me oso wen i using single string input in these function~

Comment: Easiest way for your call in f20: 
suggestion = cellfun(@checkSpelling, word, 'UniformOutput', 0)

Comment: it shows me the error, "??? Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
Source: Microsoft Word
Description: String too long
Help File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\WDMAIN11.CHM
Help Context ID: 9201
"

Comment: Check your input for which word this happens please.

Comment: i have single input for my word now, but still return me d error